# why jqGrid wont load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i have the following setup for the `Jqgrid` pivot version this was extracted from [code for pivot](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pivotexample)  but when ran it gave a `javascript` error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null
>   reference  jquery.jqGrid.min.js, line 504 character 98

how do i fix this?

the data comes as `json` from `C#`

**here is my MVC action**

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProducts() {

        var coll = new List<SampleProductModel>();

        //"CategoryName":"Beverages","ProductName":"Steeleye Stout","Country":"UK","Price":"1008.0000","Quantity":"65"
        var p1 = new SampleProductModel { CategoryName = "Beverages", ProductName = "Steeleye Stout", Country = "UK", Price = "1008.0000", Quantity = "65" };
        coll.Add(p1);


        //"CategoryName":"Beverages","ProductName":"Steeleye Stout","Country":"UK","Price":"1008.0000","Quantity":"65"
        var p2 = new SampleProductModel { CategoryName = "Beverages", ProductName = "Big John", Country = "UK", Price = "1008.0000", Quantity = "65" };
        coll.Add(p2);

        //{"CategoryName":"Beverages","ProductName":"Laughing Lumberjack Lager","Country":"USA","Price":"140.0000","Quantity":"10"},
        var p3 = new SampleProductModel { CategoryName = "Beverages", ProductName = "Laughing Lumberjack Lager", Country = "USA", Price = "140.0000", Quantity = "10" };
        coll.Add(p3);


        //{"CategoryName":"Beverages","ProductName":"Laughing Lumberjack Lager","Country":"USA","Price":"140.0000","Quantity":"10"},
        var p4 = new SampleProductModel { CategoryName = "Beverages", ProductName = "Jims", Country = "USA", Price = "140.0000", Quantity = "10" };
        coll.Add(p4);

        return Json(coll, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**here is my code that was extracted from the above link and modified to take C# json data**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script>

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('jqPivot',
                        "http://localhost:53721/Home/GetProducts",
                        // pivot options
                        {
                            xDimension : [
                                {dataName: 'CategoryName', label : 'Category', width: 90},
                                {dataName: 'ProductName', label : 'Product', width:90}
                            ],
                            yDimension : [
                                {dataName: 'Country'}
                            ],
                            aggregates : [
                                {member : 'Price', aggregator : 'sum', width:50, label:'Sum'},
                                {member : 'Quantity', aggregator : 'sum', width:50, label:'Qty'}
                            ],
                            rowTotals: true,
                            colTotals : true

                        },
                        // grid options
                        {
                            width: 700,
                            rowNum : 10,
                            pager: "#pager",
                            caption: "Amounts and quantity by category and product"
                        });
            })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You try to load the data from `53721` port, It will not work if it's not the same port from which HTML page is loaded. See [the same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Moreover you should never post an error in `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. You should remade the test using `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` version instead and to post the corresponding error message. You should include `grid.locale-en.js` before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about jqgrid but I had a suspicion that perhaps the versions you have of jquery and jqgrid might not be compatible. So I looked it up, and your version of jqgrid seems to be version 4.6.0 where the most current version seems to be 5.0.2 :

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php

So perhaps try updating it?

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

Comment: im using the free version beyond 4.6 owned by gurrido right which is not free

Comment: @Oleg    hi oleg i know you are not part of this thread but i know you are currently maintaining jqgrid free version so you be kind enough to show me how to fix this issue?

Comment: @ANP: I read your last comment by chance only. I get notification only if you post the comment to some my old answer or to some post where I wrote *my comment* before. You can search [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users) for "Oleg" and you will see 54 pages with users having the same name. Stackovrflow can't resolve the name if no other information (my answer or comment) exists.